# How to "Paste as plain text" by default in Joomla 3.8 TinyMce editor?

Tags: joomla, tinymce, paste

As the title says, I need to make this default as users are pasting terribly formatted text to the editor.

I have read similar threads where it says I should add some code to TinyMCE.init section in the file \plugins\editors\tinyMCE\tinymce.php, but there is no such section in this file.

BR,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You will indeed need to set the `paste_as_text` option to true in your `.init`. You can read more about the options for the `paste` plugins here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/

Comment: Thanks, I have read all these already, but the problem is, I cannot find the place (file) in Joomla 3.8 where TinyMCE init function is located :(

Answer (score 0):

I've been reviewing the TinyMCE 4 configuration documentation and searching the Joomla! where to change these parameters:
[https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_as_text][1]

Although the plugin does not offer these options in the settings, I was able to edit directly in the file code.

```
sitejoomla/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php
```

At approximately lines 652, look for 'paste_data_images' and add the parameter to paste in plain text as below:

```
'paste_data_images' => $ allowImgPaste,
'paste_as_text' => true,
```

Now by default when pasting (Ctrl + v) in the editor the text will be cleared without html tags and other dirt code from where it copied.

> **Test version of tools**
>   Joomla! 3.9.x
>   Editor - TinyMCE - 4.5.x 2005-2019

Comment: Please be advised that StackOverflow has an English-only policy. Check here for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: OK, sorry
I delete the translation